# Save Segmented Character Result in sequence

Tags: matlab

- I have loaded images into matlab workspace to do a character segmentation process for word images. Ex: data(1).png, data(2).png, and so on.
- The segmentation process, will give multiple image as output for every segmented character. Word images contain various amount of character, so the output also will vary. For example, Output of segmented result for image = data(1).png become data(1)_1.png, data(1)_2.png, data(1)_3.png, and data(2).png become data(2)_1.png, data(2)_2.png and so on.

Lately, I had done it manually, but the data set will be bigger and it is time-wasting to run segmentation for images one by one.
Are there any suggestions on what should I do to make it simple and more effective to get the result for every segmented character (in sequence)?

```
%// Save %
[L,num] = bwlabel(im);
for z= 1 : num
    bw= ismember( L, z);
    %// Construct filename for this particular image.
    %// Change basefilename for each word images %
    baseFileName = sprintf(data,'.%d.png', y);
    y=y+1;
    %// Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    %// Do the write to disk.
    imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
    subplot(2,2,4);
    pause(1);
    imshow(bw);
end
%// y=y+1;
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the .png file in your directory and then run your function for each of them.

```
myfolder = 'C:\myfolder';                   % folder path
files = dir(fullfile(dirName,'*.png') );   
files = {files.name}';                      %Name of your .png image"

%then run your function

for i = 1:length(files)
img = imread(files{i});
.......
end
```

And i think that you have better to put your segmented image in a new folder.